# MongoDB: query within document

Tags: mongodb

I have my mongodb document like this...

```
{
"semantics" : [
                {
                "text": "abc gave payment to xyz",
                "action": "gave"
                },
                {
                "text": "abc wanted quicker solution",
                "action": "want"
                }
            ],
"keyword" : [
                {
                "word":"payment",
                "imp":0.91
                },
                {
                "word":"solution",
                "imp":0.7
                }
            ]
}
```

The requirement is to find `action` values for those words whose importance is more than 0.9.

In the above case, `payment` has importance more than 0.9 and, hence, should be considered. `payment` exists in one of the array and the `action` value in it is `gave`.

I am requesting help in constructing mongodb query for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first use mapReduce:

```
db.collection.mapReduce( 
function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.keyword.length; i++) {
        if (this.keyword[i].imp >= 0.9) {
                emit(this.keyword[i].word, this.semantics)

        }
    }
},  
function(key, values) { }, 
{
    out: {merge: 'result'}, 
    finalize: function(key, semantics) {
        var result;
        for (var i = 0; i < semantics.length; i++) {
            if (semantics[i].text.indexOf(key) != -1) {
                result = {key: semantics[i].action};
            } 
        }

    return result;
    }
)
```

We don't care about the reduce function here since map will return `{word with imp >= 0.9: the whole semantics}`.

Later, before storing the result into `result` collection, finialize function is called and it goes through all semantics associated with a word and fetches all actions related to texts that contain the key word.

After this, you can `db.result.find()` to see the result, you will see some null result because not all key has a matched text and action, you need to clean up a bit.

Comment: this provides the whole document and not a part of it... the above would result as
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599e7cacb77f432e4da6069d"),
    "semantics" : [ 
        {
            "action" : "gave"
        }, 
        {
            "action" : "want"
        }
    ]
}

the output should have only "gave"

Comment: @srikanth what do you want the result be

Comment: the output should be "gave"... so basically it has to first filter word whose imp is >0.9 and then search that word in the text field. the text which contains this word, that's action to be resulted...

Comment: not aware of mapreduce .. the query executes with an error  as unexpected token return

i added a comment to the extra } 
....
function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.keyword.length; i++) {
        if (this.keyword[i].imp >= 0.9) {
                emit(this.keyword[i].word, this.semantics)
            }
        }
    },
//},  
function(key, values) { }, ....

Comment: Edited, actually you can correct on your own it's not hard to notice the error. It works during my test. You can play with it, since you have all data. Hope it helps

Comment: i tried modifying the above bit more... but i get null in the values field...not able to understand why? 
db.reviews.mapReduce( 
function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.keywords.length; i++) {
        if (this.keywords[i].relevance >= 0.8) {
                emit({key: this._id},
                        {data :[ {keyword: this.keywords[i].text, sent: this.semantic_roles}]} );
            } }  },
function(key, values) { }, 
{
    out: {merge: 'result'}, 
    finalize: function(key,values) {       
             return values;
    }
    }
)

Comment: yes, you need to modify the 'result'. You can fire up another query to clean 'result' collection. Something like 'db.collection.remove({xxxx: {$exist: false}})'